# Duplicate and modify local file (e.g. via File System Access API?)

Tags: javascript, download, save, filesystems, save-as

Background: An XML file is to be loaded* into a web app. Various parameters are changed there. The file is then downloaded again. Depending on the browser settings, the modified XML file is either saved in the download folder or the 'save as/browse directories' window opens.

Issue: These XML files can be in different local folders and while you are making the modifications in the webapp, it can happen that you are also uploading files from other folders or downloading them to other folders on another platform. This results in having to constantly browse the local file system in the 'save as/browse directories' window or copying files from the standard download folder, and wasting a lot of time.

Ideal case: The file is automatically downloaded to the original source folder, is named the same but contains the suffix "_mod" or similar.

My research: I came across the File System Access API, which allows reading and writing of local files and folder structures. The API also works on the browsers used for my purposes. However, it seems that the user still has to specify a directory in order to create a new file. Or you can overwrite the original file, which would be suboptimal for my purposes. So my question: Is there any way to easily duplicate a file and customize its content (it doesn't have to be via File System Access API, maybe there are other JS or PHP solutions)? Best solution that has emerged so far would be if the user selects a file and straight after that the folder where it is located. I haven't yet tried whether this really works, as I don't think it makes sense or feels intuitive.

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

*Edit: The contents of the file are read and stored in a JS variable.

Edit 2: I can't use node.js.

Comment: If the file is less than 5mb and doesn't contain confidential information, then you could save it to [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in the users browser. However, this kind of problem is usually solved by storing the document and revisions on the server, which can also manage document checkout flags and permissions checks.

Comment: @Yogi Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the files can be larger than 5MB and it is also necessary that they are stored locally. However, the file per se does not have to be saved on the server. I may have expressed myself incorrectly: The contents of the file are read and saved as a variable in JS and modified.

Comment: I don't think it is possible given these limitations. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55489025/it-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-save-a-file-to-specific-directory).  The only alternatives would be creating a browser extension or a native app that run with higher permissions. These would be good solutions if your users are frequently editing the XML files.  Building an extension is not too difficult: [Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/What_are_WebExtensions)

Comment: Probably you can use `options` object in the `showSaveFilePicker()/showOpenFilePicker()`  methods. Both provide a `startIn` directory or `id`s to "remember different directories" as per documentation.